Set an Android TV app not possible to run
I'm developing an embedded Android TV for a specific customer device.
It must not be possible for the user to launch this app and the "Start" / "Open" option under app settings must not be present.
How the apk can be setted in this way?
I don't find anything about change app settings

if there is no main launcher activity then there wont be anything to open

If you do not want the app to appear in the launcher, do not have a launcher activity in the app (i.e., remove the launcher <intent-filter> from the <activity> element).
Your bigger problem is Settings ("the "Start" / "Open" option under app settings must not be present"). If this Android TV device is running your own custom build of the Android OS, you control the behavior of the Settings app and presumably can make code changes to Settings to filter out your desired app. If this is an "off the shelf" Android TV device, then your app will appear in Settings, or not, based on the device manufacturer's own rules.
Note that if your app cannot be started, it will never run, unless some other app is able to use an explicit Intent to invoke some component in your app.
